# Cierre de Jframe si el ingreso es exitoso

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

ok tengo la siguiente pregunta, estoy haciendo una app e inicialmente tengo 3 jframe (formulario1. formulario2 y formulario3).

este es el formulario 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posee 2 botones, uno llama al formulario 2 y el otro cierra la aplicacion. este formulario debe permanever abierto hasta que se realice el ingreso exitosamente.

aca el codigo de los botones.

```
private void BtnIngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    formulario2 form2 = new formulario2();
    form2.setVisible(true);
}                                           

private void BtnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Este es el formulario 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca hay 2 JText y un boton el boton este es el codigo del boton ingresar:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(txtUser.getText()) && "12345".equals(txtpass.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso exitoso");
        formulario3 form3 = new formulario3();
        form3.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso fallido");
    }
}
```

y por ultimo el formulario 3 que este se abre siempre y cuando el ingreso sea exitoso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ok la aplicacion funciona, pero lo que deseo hacer es que el formularfio inicial se mantenga abierto hasta que el usuario ingrese exitosamente, en caso de ingresar correctamente, se cierran el formulario 1 y 2 y queda visible solo l formulario 3, pero no he podido lograr esto.

Coloque el dispose en el boton ingresar del primer frame pero se cerraba al momento e hacerle clik al boton y no es lo que deseo, quiero que se cierre al momento de que se abre el formulario 3,

¿como puedo hacer esto? gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una propiedad en el JFrame2, que se llame ingresoExitosamente.

```
public class JFrame2 extends JFrame {

    private boolean ingresoExitosamente = false;

//luego agregamos un método para avisar cuando esta propiedad cambie.

    protected void ingresoExitosamente(boolean ok) {
        if (ingresoExitosamente != ok) {
           ingresoExitosamente = ok;
           firePropertyChange("ingresoExitosamente", !ok, ok);
        }
    }
//cambiamos tu método para cambiar esa propiedad cuando ingrese ok
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(txtUser.getText()) && "12345".equals(txtpass.getText())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso exitoso");
        formulario3 form3 = new formulario3();
        form3.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        ingresoExitosamente(true); ///aquí cambiamos propiedad
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingreso fallido");
    }
} 

}
```

En el JFrame1 ahora necesitamos escuchar al JFrame2, por lo que requerimos implementar PropertyChangeListener.

```
public JFrame1 extends JFrame implements java.beans.propertyChangeListener {

//aquí escuchamos los cambios de propiedad de JFrame2, pero solo la que nos interesa
@Override
public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    if ("ingresoExitosamente".equals(e.getPropertyName())
         && (boolean)e.getNewValue()) {
       dispose(); //cerramos JFrame1
    }
}

//Solo falta avisar al JFrame2 que queremos escuchar sus cambios de propiedades
private void BtnIngresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    formulario2 form2 = new formulario2();
    form2.addPropertyChangeListener(this); ///aquí le decimos que nos avise de cambios
    form2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba